# Proving an eigenspace is a T-Invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-theory

I want to know if I'm going about this proof the correct way.

**Problem Statement:** Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$, and let $λ$ be a scalar. The eigenspace $V^{(λ)}$ is the set of eigenvectors of $T$ with eigenvalue $λ$, together with $\textbf{0}$. Prove that $V^{(λ)}$ is a $T$-invariant subspace.

So I need to show that $T(V^{(λ)})\subseteq V^{(λ)}$.

Since $V^{(λ)}$ is the set of eigenvectors of the matrix $T$ corresponding to $λ$, that meants that for any $\textbf{v}\in V^{(λ)}$, we have $T\textbf{v}=λ\textbf{v}$.

Clearly, $T\textbf{v}\in T(V^{(λ)})$.
Then we know that for any $\textbf{v}\in V^{(λ)}$, $\text{span}(\textbf{v})\in V^{(λ)}$. Thus, $λ\textbf{v}\in V^{(λ)}$. Since $T\textbf{v}=λ\textbf{v}$, then $T\textbf{v}\in V^{(λ)}$. So then $T(V^{(λ)})\subseteq V^{(λ)}$?

Comment: Are you asking to verify your proof?

Comment: Yes. We just learned about linear operators and T-invariant sub spaces the other day and I wanted to make sure that my logic is correct.

Comment: It is indeed correct. I just proved the span$(\textbf{v}) \in V^{(\lambda)}$ part below.

Comment: Is the converse the case, i.e., is every invariant subspace the eigenspace associated to some eigenvalue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Just a small thing to add.

If $\textbf{v}\in V^{(λ)}$ then $T \textbf{v}= \lambda \textbf{v}$.

Claim: If $\textbf{v} \in V^{(\lambda)}$ then, $k\textbf{v} \in V^{(\lambda)}$, for any scalar $k$.

Proof: $T(k\textbf{v})= k\ (T(\textbf{v}))=k\ (\lambda\textbf{v})= \lambda (k\textbf{v}) \implies k\textbf{v}\in V^{(\lambda)}$

Similarly you can show that, $\textbf{v}_1,\textbf{v}_2 \in V^{(\lambda)} \implies \textbf{v}_1+\textbf{v}_2 \in V^{(\lambda)}$.

Comment: awesome! I actually was going to add something similar to my write up of the proof. thank you!

Comment: Could you do the addition part?

Comment: Yes, I understand how to do the addition part. Since $T$ is a matrix, we'd have $T(v_{1}+v_{2})=T(v_{1})+T(v_{2})=Tv_{1}+Tv_{2}=\lambda v_{1}+\lambda v_{2}=\lambda (v_{1}+v_{2})$ correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct! If I cleared your doubts properly, accept the answer to make the status of the question complete.